# Parsing URL arguments using regular expressions

Tags: c, regex, json, apache, http

I am trying to parse url arguments using regex.

Here is my url:

http://127.0.0.1/privet/register?action=cancel&user=xx.gcp234@gmail.com

Although simple, could someone assist me in writing a regular expression for the following URL arguments:

```
action=cancel&user=xx.gcp234%40gmail.com
```

Here is my regular expression:
    "/^([\a-z.-])\=([\a-z.-])$/

I just need to print the following info:

action = cancel

user = xx.gcp234@gmail.com

and send this back as a JSON formatted string.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You should *amend your question* and pony-up the expressions you've tried so far. "Whats wrong with my regular expressions?" is bound to get better feedback than what you've asked, which fundamentally boils down to "Write my regular expressions for me."

Comment: @WhozCraig..Thank you for the suggestion. I have updated my post accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adopted from Corona688's post on [Unix Linux Forums](http://www.unix.com/programming/178989-how-use-regular-expression-c-c.html) using the `regex.h` library (available in unix) and returning the bite location of parameters following `=` separated by `&`. You'll have to find and download a regex library if you aren't using Unix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>
int main(void)
{
        regex_t reg;
        const char *regex="([^=&?]+)=([^&]+)";
        const char *str="http://127.0.0.1/privet/register?action=cancel&user=xx.gcp234@gmail.com";
        regmatch_t matches[16];

        regcomp(&reg, regex, REG_EXTENDED);

        if(regexec(&reg, str, 16, matches, 0) == 0)
        {
                printf("regex /%s/ matched string '%s' at bytes %d-%d\n",
                        regex, str, matches[0].rm_so, matches[0].rm_eo);
        }
        else
                printf("regex /%s/ does not match string '%s'\n", regex, str);
}
```

Comment: what does match[1] return? Does it return user = xx.gcp234@gmail.com?

Comment: Yes, as well as cancel.

Comment: I am trying to parse the above url in C and I get an error saying " error: too many arguments for format [-Werror=format-extra-args]
   sscanf(text, "action=(\w*)&user=(\S*)", action, user)"  Here is my code: 
     char text[] = "http://127.0.0.1/privet/register?action=start&user=ap.gcp2106@gmail.com";
     char action[10];
     char user[25];

  sscanf(text, "action=(\w*)&user=(\S*)", action, user);

Comment: Sorry, I had posted the regex parse in javascript. I've editted it for C although regex.h is only available in Unix.

Comment: ...that solution worked well..however, how do I extract action=cancel and user=xx.gcp234@gmail.com separately. I just need cancel and xx.gcp234@gmail.com for comparison. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet parses the URL

http://127.0.0.1/privet/register?action=cancel&user=xx.gcp234@gmail.com

```
    regex_t reg;
            const char *regex = "([^=&?]+)=([^&]+)";
            //const char *regex = "action=(\w*)&user=(\S*)";
            const char *str = "http://127.0.0.1/privet/register?action=cancel&user=xx.gcp234@gmail.com";
            LOGDEBUG("r->uri : %s\n", r->unparsed_uri);
            size_t maxGroups = 10;
            regmatch_t groupArray[maxGroups];

            regcomp(&reg, regex, REG_EXTENDED);

            if (regexec(&reg, str, maxGroups, groupArray, 0) == 0) {
                unsigned int g = 0;
                for (g = 0; g < maxGroups; g++) {
                    if (groupArray[g].rm_so == (size_t) -1)
                        break;  // No more groups

                    char sourceCopy[strlen(str) + 1];
                    strcpy(sourceCopy, str);
                    sourceCopy[groupArray[g].rm_eo] = 0;
                    LOGDEBUG("Group %u: [%2u-%2u]: %s\n", g, groupArray[g].rm_so,
                            groupArray[g].rm_eo, sourceCopy + groupArray[g].rm_so);

}
```

This returns matched groups.